# How can I query a jsonb array to find if it contains a value from a query list?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Currently my table looks something like this

```
 id |                 companies                 
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"companies": [{"name": "Google", "industry": "TECH"}, 
    |                {"name": "FOX News", "industry": "MEDIA"}]}
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | {"companies": [{"name": "Honda", "industry": "AUTO"}]}
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------
  3 | {"companies": [{"name": "Nike", "industry": "SPORTS"}]}
```

I want to grab all the rows were the `companies` JSONB array contains a company with industry in a the list `["TECH", "SPORTS"]`.

In this example, the query would return rows 1 and 3.

I'm unsure of how to do this due to the nesting involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` and `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.companies -> 'companies') x(obj)
    where x.obj ->> 'industry' in ('TECH', 'SPORTS')
)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was playing around with `jsonb_array_elements()` after posting but looks like I was using incorrect syntax as its input!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write this, is to use the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from the_table t
where t.companies -> 'companies' @> '[{"industry": "TECH"}]'
   or t.companies -> 'companies' @> '[{"industry": "SPORTS"}]'
```

This could make use of a GIN index on `companies`